# PHP Error "T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING"

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I'm getting this error from when I updated my SQL query.

The error is on this line:

```
$update_sql = "UPDATE table SET `column1` = IF(LENGTH('$_POST['column1']')=0, column1, '$_POST['column1']'), `column2` =  '".$_POST['column2']."' WHERE name='".$_POST['movie_name']."';";
```

The error is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What's with the downvote?

Comment: When you get errors like these, the easiest way to find the bug is usually to do something like `echo "generated update sql: " . $update_sql;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad string concatenation.

```
$update_sql = "UPDATE movies SET `nowvideo` = IF(LENGTH('" . $_POST['nowvideo'] . "')=0, nowvideo, '" . $_POST['nowvideo'] . "'), `nowvideohd` =  '".$_POST['nowvideohd']."' WHERE name='".$_POST['movie_name']."';";
```

As a side note, your query is very insecure. You're putting data directly from the form into a query. Read up on SQL injection & sanitizing your queries.

I'd also read up on PDO if you're planning on securing your queries anyway.

Comment: @Stayner I'm going to use it at home only so I don't think it's a problem, but is mysql escape string ok to sanitize it?

Comment: `mysql_*` queries are deprecated now, so using PDO is recommended. You can read up on PDO here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php. However, if `mysql_real_escape_string` is a must, it will sanitize the query.

Comment: @Stayner Thanks again!And mysqli_ instead of mysql, right?

Comment: If you're not going to go down the PDO route, then yes use `mysqli_*` to replace your `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: +1 for side note about sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

You should save the POST variable into a variable, perform the checks and clean to avoid SQL injection

```
//Safe get the variables
$nowVideo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nowVideo');
$nowVideoHd = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nowvideohd');
$movieName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'movie_name');

if (!empty($movieName)) {
    //Avoid sql injection
    $nowVideo = mysqli_real_escape_string($connectionLink, $nowVideo);
    $nowVideoHd = mysqli_real_escape_string($connectionLink, $nowVideo);
    $movieName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connectionLink, $movieName);

    $update_sql = 'UPDATE movies SET nowvideo = ' . (empty($nowVideo) ? 'nowvideo' : "'$nowVideo'") . ', nowvideohd = ' . $nowVideoHd . " WHERE name = '$movieName'";
}
else {
    //Show error
}
```

You should set a default value for **nowVideoHd** in case that the nowVideoHd variable is empty. You should set it like the $nowVideo var or with a default value.

Answer (score 0):

all the $_POST['columnx'] should be ".$_POST['columnx']."